# Catch The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https' error

Tags: c#, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I need to be able to catch this specific error

> The provided URI scheme 'http' is invalid; expected 'https'

I have a method that is trying an https binding, if it fails with the above error I then want it to try the http binding.

How would I catch this? I have been able to catch it by catching everything, but i just want to catch that one specific error.

Comment: What type of exception is it? For example, a duplicatekey exception, null reference exception?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it came under a Parameters Exception.